# How to get count of occurrence of specific value for each row SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table named ReviewFact which has the following attributes:

```
- CategoryID (Primary Key)
- Star_Rating (Primary Key)
- No_of_Reviews
```

CategoryID refers to specific product, Star_Rating refers to a star rating given by users, No_of_Reviews refers to how many users gave this rating.

I have to write an SQL query which shows the number of 5 star reviews for each category.

I have come up with the following:

```
SELECT r.CategoryID, r.NUMBER_OF_REVIEWS
FROM REVIEWFACT r
WHERE r.Stars = 5
ORDER BY r.NUMBER_OF_REVIEWS desc;
```

Using this I get the number of reviews for rows which have 5 star reviews, but not for ones which don't. The ones which don't should have the count as 0. How do I go about solving this?

If there are the following rows in the table:

```
CategoryID        Star_Rating        No_of_Reviews
1                 5                  10
2                 5                  4
3                 2                  9
```

The query should return

```
CategoryID        No_of_Reviews
1                 10
2                 4
3                 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by category and sum conditionally:

```
select
  categoryid,
  sum(case when stars = 5 then no_of_reviews else 0 end) as no_of_reviews
from reviewfact 
group by categoryid
order by no_of_reviews;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a `case`:

```
SELECT r.CategoryID,
       (CASE WHEN r.starts = 5 THEN r.NUMBER_OF_REVIEWS ELSE 0 END)
FROM REVIEWFACT r
ORDER BY r.NUMBER_OF_REVIEWS desc;
```

Comment: This works but it returns multiple records containing same CategoryID. If CategoryID 6 has two star rating reviews, 2 and 5, it returns a row for each containing count of 5 stars, but I just want it to contain count for five star (if it exists) or otherwise return 0 for each category ID.

Comment: @AndyrK . . . That is how your sample data is constructed.  If you have *another* question, then ask it as a question.  If you change this question, you will invalidate the answers of people who answered the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Same, with IF statement:

```
SELECT r.CategoryID, IF(r.Stars = 5, r.NUMBER_OF_REVIEWS, 0) as bestReviews
FROM REVIEWFACT r
ORDER BY r.NUMBER_OF_REVIEWS desc;
```